# OpenGL/SDL problem in Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, sdl

I have a C-code which I have not managed to run
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/problem-sdl.png

The problem is in OpenGL or SDL.
I do not have SDL.h at /usr/local/SDL/SDL.h, so gcc cannot find it.

I have SDL.h installed by MacPorts at /opt/local/include/SDL/SDL.h.

I tried to copy it to /Masi/local/SDL/SDL.h unsuccessfully at the folder  by

```
cp /opt/local/include/SDL/SDL.h /
```

and by

```
cp /opt/local/include/SDL/SDL.h /Masi/local/SDL/
```

I tried to solve the problem by creationg a symlink by

```
$ln -s /opt/local/include/SDL/SDL.h /Masi/local/SDL/SDL.h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Ubuntu does not have them by default (at least the development versions). For my own little program I just installed *libsdl1.2-dev* and *mesa-common-dev* (OpenGL).

For the build process I use scons which produces the following commands:

```
gcc -o src/geom.o -c -Wall -ansi src/geom.c
gcc -o src/main.o -c -Wall -ansi src/main.c
gcc -o test src/main.o src/geom.o -lSDL -lGL
```

If you install the libraries in some non-standard location, you might have to specify your own include (-I) and library (-L) paths.

Comment: Thank you for the piece of information! I had them in my Ubuntu. The problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is obviously that gcc cannot find SDL.h. Do you have it in /usr/local/SDL/SDL.h? Do you include it like so: #include <SDL/SDL.h> ?

Answer (score 4):

the simplest way to get all the compiler flags for SDL is by using `sdl-config`:

```
gcc sdl_gl_1.c $(sdl-config --cflags --libs) -lGL -lGLU
```

Comment: I get the following error: $gcc sdl_gl_1.c $(sdl-config --cflags --libs) -lGL -lGLU
ld: library not found for -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: libGL is the OpenGL library. It is usually installed with your graphics card drivers.